# MySQL server and Android app connectivity

Tags: android, mysql, database

I am trying to create a database for my android app and I want to know some efficient ways to connect my android app to my database on the MySQL server.
Please suggest some ways that are better in many possible ways!

Comment: create the api in php which connects to mysql db and call that api in the android app... so simple :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use webservice or apis made by server side language like PHP,JSP ,or Rails etc. to connect with mysql database and and return JSON data that you can parse it to in your android app. [here is the link to refer](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: Is it secure?? I mean, php script can be accessed by  anyone. So, what are the issues regarding security?

Comment: Create a self-signed server SSL certificate and deploy on your web server

Answer (score 0):

You can send GET or POST request to the server with your script, for example written on PHP, that retrieves the data from the DB and returns it to your device.